# .htaccess complex regular expression

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make an complex rewrite rule in my `.htaccess`, I have the URL:

```
domain.com/?w={WHAT}&l={WHERE}&r={RADIUS}&f={FILTER}
```

I want to redirect to the follow URL structure:

1. if w and l are not empty

   ```
   domain/{WHAT}-jobs-in-{WHERE}
   ```
2. if w is not empty and l is empty

   ```
   domain/{WHAT}-jobs
   ```
3. if w is empty and l is not empty

   ```
   domain/jobs-in-{WHERE}
   ```
4. To all above if there are other params then put them at the end in the form:

   ```
   domain/{WHAT}-jobs-in-{WHERE}/?r={RADIUS}&f={FILTER}
   ```

Comment: Could you add what you have tried in your question please?

Comment: Also, what is "empty"?  Do you mean the parameter is missing altogether, or does it just not have a value? A few examples are always nice.

Comment: Yes, empty mean the parameter is missing, not set or the value is empty

Answer (score 0):

These 3 rules should do the job:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if not domain.com then bail out
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^w=([^&]+)&l=([^&]+)(?:&(.+))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1-jobs-in-%2?%3 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^w=([^&]+)(?:&l=&)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1-jobs?%2 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:w=&)?l=([^&]+)(?:&(.+))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /jobs-in-%1?%2 [L,NE,R=302]

# replace + by - recursively
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^+]*)\+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R]
```

Comment: Hey anubhava, thanks for the fast response. I will test it and write you back. Do you thing in this rules the order of w and l is importand or not? Because sometimes the order can be ?w=bla&l=blu and ?l=blue&w=bla .. what do you thing?

Comment: Well this code expects order to be maintained. It might be possible to make it order agnostic but that will make these rules even more complicated.

Comment: Hmm, that means I need to fix the order to be ever the same. Ok I will try it. One thing: can you please add the domain name in this rules. Because I have different domains and for each one there are different words for "jobs", thats why I need the domain.com in the rules.

Comment: One thing: if the keyword in w or l is buidet from 2 keywords like: account manager, then the rewrite is placing an "+" separator and it should be an dash: Example: domain.com/?w=account+manager&l=new+york -> domain.com/account-manager-jobs-in-new-york . Is this possible by the convertion?

Comment: `domain.com` condition can be easily added. Do you want to replace `+` with something else in redirected URI?

Comment: Yes I want to replace + with - .